# How to add IMEI number to product to check waranty

Tags: magento

I want to add functionality to check product warranty using IMEI number.
if a user ordered more then 1 qty  then their IMEI number are also different.

I am fresher of magento

So please share idea how it is possible.

Comment: Please provide some information about what you have done so far and add this to your question.

Comment: I want to that user enter  IMEI number and check their warranty of product in magetno. 

So how we add  IMEI number of product in magetno when a order placed

Comment: it seems that you need a customization in core magento files or hire a personal developer ;)

Comment: @VishnuBhadoriya : do you have any idea how it is implement using new module?

Comment: it is very long process cannot be answered here

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?